# What powers the Federation skimmers in David Weber's 'Safehold'?

Tags: safehold

In David Weber's *Safehold* series, the character Merlin Athrawes uses a recon skimmer to covertly travel around Safehold.  Merlin sometimes uses it to go into low orbit, and he more frequently uses it to travel at least Mach 5.

That's a lot of required power.

I've listened to the first four audiobooks, and I can't remember a mention of the skimmer's fuel or power source.  I don't remember Merlin or his semi-sentient computer Owl ever fueling the skimmer, either.

The [wikia page on the recon skimmer](http://safehold.wikia.com/wiki/Recon_skimmer) doesn't mention the drive technology or fuel type.

What does the recon skimmer use as a power/fuel source?  Does it require refueling at all?

Comment: Assuming the skimmer is similar to the *Asp* class grav combat vehicle shown in Weber's "Starfire" collaborations with Steve White, which it does resemble from your description. it's most likely a fusion power device. So fuel would be hydrogen isotopes or maybe Helium-3, and refuel frequency  would depend on use and efficiency - do you have figures for the mass of the vehicle so we can calculate that?